# Отображение картинок по значению взятому из поля для ввода

Tags: php

Если набрать 1,2,3=> будет зима, 4,5,6 => весна, 7,8,9 => лето, 10,11,12 => осень, но пока что не могу понять что не так..
Вот мой код: в php зеро! Код взял на киберфоруме по частям собрал..

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" value="" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Show image" name="but">
</form>
```

код php:

```
<?php
    $pic = "Зима...<br><img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Haanja_2010_01_1.jpg/1200px-Haanja_2010_01_1.jpg>";
    if ($_POST['but'] == true)
    {
        echo $pic;
    }
    $pic="Весна...<br><img src=https://comments.ua/img/20180110122417.jpg>";
    if ($_POST['but'] == true)
    {
        echo $pic;
    }
    $pic="Лето...<br><img src=https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzAzMy8zMDIvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrXzcxMzI2NjgxLmpwZw==>";
    if ($_POST['but'] == true)
    {
        echo $pic;
    }
    $pic="Осень...<br><img src=https://hyser.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1-23-880x528.jpg>";
    if ($_POST['but'] == true)
    {
        echo $pic;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала проверьте, что форма отправлена

```
if(isset($_POST['but'])){
```

Далее получите введенное число (предварительно добавив `name="month"` к инпуту)

```
     $month =  intval($_POST['month']);
```

Затем используя,  например, оператор `switch` напишите условие для определения времени года

```
    switch($month){
         case 1:
         case 2:
         case 3: $season = 'зима'; break;
         case 4:
         case 5:
         case 6: $season = "весна"; break;
         ....
         default: throw new \Exception("invalid month value");
    }
```

Определите картинки для каждого времени года:

```
     $images = [
           "зима" => "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Haanja_2010_01_1.jpg/1200px-Haanja_2010_01_1.jpg",
           "весна" => "", 
            ....
     ];
```

выведите время года и картинку

```
     echo "$season <br/> <img src='${images[$season]}'/>";
```

Не забудьте закрыть скобку

```
}
```

В целом `switch` можно заменить на массив:

```
 $seasons = [
            1 => "зима",
            2 => "зима",
            .... 
      ];

 $season = $seasons[$month];
```